Telnet to device using Python
I am trying to send a series of commands and read responses from a Microprocessor using and Telnet connection. The commands are sent to the microprocessor through a ethernet to serial connection passing through a Lantronix XPort (XP1001000-05R). The command I am using to test if the connection is working is *idn?, when sent using PuTTY the response is:
Flann 625-03V2 PVRA
Serial Number 000000
Hardware Version V1.0
System Version V1.0
Motor Version unknown

I've tried using socket:
import socket

TCP_IP = '10.1.5.126'
TCP_PORT = 10001
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = bytes("*IDN?"+"\n", 'ansi')
#MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"
 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE)
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()

print ("received data:", data)

The response I get from the print is:
received data: b'\xff\xfb\x01\xff\xfb\x03\xff\xfa,j`\xff\xf0'

I've also tried using the telnet library:
import telnetlib 
  
# Connect to the Telnet server 
tn = telnetlib.Telnet("10.1.5.126", 10001) 
  
# Send a command to the server 
tn.write(b"*idn?\n") 
  
# Read the output from the server 
output = tn.read_all() 
  
# Print the output 
print(output) 
tn.close() 

But this seems to get stuck on the output read.all line

Try tn.read_until('\n') in the telnetlib variant, maybe multiple times to receive all lines.

Try something less crazy than "ansi". I'm guessing you meant to encode into "us-ascii"? My Python fails with "unknown encoding" for "ansi".

Could it be that the remote side needs \r\n line endings?

Thank you, it now works with the read_until and adding the \r  into the message
